# Howto use a c++ template typedef in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I'd like to typedef a template type and use this type in a second template class.

First I defined the typedef with a helper struct

```
template<class T>
struct MyList {
   typedef std::map<int, T> Type;  
};
```

and then used it in the second template:

```
 template <class T>
    class MySecondClass {
    public:
       MySecondClass(MyList<T>& list) : list_(list) {}
    private:
       MyList<T>::Type list_;   
   };
```

Unfortunately, the use of  `MyListT& list;` doesn't work and creates an error.

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: First I get a warning : c4346 dependent name is not a type and then a error C2146 syntax.

Comment: plz post the full error (line + message) as the compiler/linker generates it. you should do that on any question you have about errors/warnings

Comment: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier list_

Comment: you are missing a ;. look on the 4 line in the second code block.

Comment: Ah thank you. I just rewrote a small example from my real working code, so i had some typos. The template problem keeps the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
template <typename T>
 class MySecondClass {
    public:
       MySecondClass(typename MyList<T>::Type& list) : list_(list) {}
    private:
       typename MyList<T>::Type& list_;   
  };
```

Comment: Great, that does it! Could you explain, what's the difference is in using the word typename before MyList ?

Answer (score 1):

`MyList<T>::Type` is not the same type as `MyList<T>` and you are mixing them in `MySecondClass`.  Also you may need a `typename` prefix on that last declaration.

Comment: It was just a typo, i redited already to MyList<T>::Type. The problem is the same. I can use this typedef only with a real type like MyList int::Type list_;  but thats not what i want, i want it for a general type T.